# order from the newest post in ionic and firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2

i want to order from the newest post that i send to firebase but this code done do the thing that i want, this code just post from the last to the new post, but i want the new post place first.

here is the typescript :

```
this.db.list('/laporan/'+this.id,{query:{limitToLast :'7'}}).subscribe(data => {

      for(var i = 0,j=0; i<data.length;i++)
      {
              this.hehe[j]=data[i];
              j++;

      }
```

here is the html

```
<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let laporanHarian of hehe;">
          Tanggal :  <span> {{ laporanHarian.mydate.day}}</span> {{ laporanHarian.mydate.month}} {{ laporanHarian.mydate.year}} <br>
          Porsi Karbohidrat :{{ laporanHarian.porsiKarbohidrat }}<br>
          Porsi Protein Hewani :{{ laporanHarian.porsiProteinHewani }}<br>
          Porsi Protein Nabati : {{ laporanHarian.porsiProteinNabati }}<br>
          Porsi lemak : {{ laporanHarian.porsiLemak }}<br>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to reverse the response array so that the newest post becomes the first element. If you are using a library like lodash, then you could use the reverse method.

Alternatively you could just modify your code like:

```
for(var i=0,j=data.length; j > -1; j--) {
         this.hehe[j-1] = data[i];
         i++;
 }
```

(The .length would return the number of elements in the array whereas the ordering will be 0 to length-1. Hence the [j-1])

Hope this helps you. Thanks.